# Using a comparison operator on a value stored as a field in the same document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to perform a `$pull` update operation on votes array in the following document

```
{ _id: 1, votes: [ 3, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8 ], threshold : 5 }
```

for which I used the following query

```
db.values.update({_id:1},{$pull:{votes:{$lt:"$threshold"}}},{})
```

This query doesn't seem to work if try to access threshold dynamically. If I try to use `{$lt:5}`, it works, but that beats my purpose.

I expect this to return the following document

```
{ _id: 1, votes: [ 5, 6, 7, 7, 8 ], threshold : 5 }
```

Is there a way that this could be done without changing the structure of my json or creating any additional fields?

Comment: I am using mongodb 3.4.0

Comment: There is an answer in the possible duplicate if you are using MongoDB 3.4